# Subdivision nothing like original

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I have a lego batman model taken from LDraw. It is really low-poly and messy, and when I use subsurf, it manages to look even worse. Is there anything I can do about this?

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

And here's a bit of wireframe:

[image]

Comment: Subsurf will not work correctly with triangle faces (tris). You can try to dissolve some diagonal edges to get quad topology or just retopologize manually this mesh.

Comment: It's not necessary. Question will be probably marked as duplicate. If you provide this mesh maybe I will be able to find some quick method to make it quad as topology is quite simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LukeD said, a mesh can not be triangulated if you want to use subsurf properly. I found you can press **Alt+J** in edit mode to make the mesh quads and n-gons.

Comment: Ngons will not work with subsurf as well :)